# Picking a random emoji from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unicode, emoji

What I want is a really simple React component that returns a random emoji out of a list of allowed ones, for readability I've just created a string with all the allowed emoji I want it to choose from and then returning a random one, but what I'm getting is the �-symbol (unicode replacement char).

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => {
  const allowedEmoji = '✌️';
  return (
    <span role="img" aria-label="hello">
      {allowedEmoji[Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedEmoji.length)]}
    </span>
  );
};
```

I'm guessing this has to do with encoding and emojis in a string taking up more than one index? Can someone please clarify this?

Comment: I guess it has to do with bite each character takes. An emogi takes 32 bits and 1 string character takes 16.

Comment: an array might be a better solution in this case

Comment: `[...allowedEmoji][Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedEmoji.length)]` will do the trick.

Comment: do `const allowedEmoji = [...'✌️'];` and best is you'd do it outside of the function.

Comment: @AZ_ no it won't because `allowedEmoji.length` is wrong. Compare `allowedEmoji.length` and `[...allowedEmoji].length`

Comment: @Thomas yeah need to create the array first then use the variable.

Comment: Adding to my first comment, you can try something like this to achieve value: https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/3d5L8jsu/